# Thread in ready state consumes CPU

Tags: multithreading, qnx

I understand that only the threads in running state actually consumes CPU but as show below by top in QNX platform, total CPU states is 99.3 which is a cumulative of four threads of which only one is in running state.

Any idea why CPU is consumed more than what running threads consume?

```
    CPU states: 99.3% user, 0.6% kernel
    CPU  0 Idle: 0.0% 
    CPU  1 Idle: 0.0% 
    Memory: 0 total, 1G avail, page size 4K
    PID   TID PRI STATE HH:MM:SS CPU  COMMAND
    704585 11  10  Run   0:01:52 24.82% App
    704585 10  10  Rdy   0:01:52 24.68% App
    704585 13  10  Rdy   0:01:52 24.53% App
    704585 16  10  Rdy   0:01:49 24.19% App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threads that are ready were in a running state when they consumed the CPU. Given the very similar CPU values, I'll bet that all of those threads are always either ready to run or running.

Comment: You mean to say, threads that are shown as ready actually are not consuming  the CPU at the particular moment? than it should release the consumption, correct?

IF they are competing for the same lock, shouldn't they be in BLOCKED state?

Comment: @Coder See updates. On your platform, `Rdy` means "ready to run" and not blocked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Threads in a RUNNING state are the only ones *currently* consuming CPU at the current instant, but those in a READY state are those that are eligible to consume CPU over an interval of time.

Your processor has two cores, so up to two threads can be RUNNING at once. Any number can be READY (i.e. unblocked and runnable, but not necessarily currently executing on a core), and those will be run according to priority and scheduling method that applies. Since you are querying the process manager for thread states, one of those two cores will at that instance obviously be running a thread in the Process manager. The other core will still be running an available READY thread from amongst the set of unblocked threads in the system, again based on priority and scheduling algorithm. This is why just one of your four threads shows as running, while the others are merely READY. That the other three threads are READY means that, assuming they are at the same priority as your other currently-running thread, the scheduler will run those threads on the available cores according to the scheduling algorithm you are using, as long as no higher priority threads are or become READY. The thread state reflects instantaneous state at the time the process manager is being asked to provide thread state information from the kernel, while the usage stat reflects activity over time and not an instantaneous state. Over a brief period of time, if you have four round robin threads all READY and at the same priority running round-robin, you would see close to 25% utilization attributable to each of the four threads. But only two can be RUNNING at any one instant if you have only two cores, and if you are busy actually getting the information about thread states then one of those two available cores is busy grabbing that info and you will only ever see up to one other thread in a RUNNING state.  If you are using QNX I suggest you read and memorize the System Architecture manual (http://www.qnx.com/download/feature.html?programid=26183). Ch. 2's discussion of thread lifecycle and scheduling addresses this question. 
Hope that helps.